# Trying to print two Models info

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

**So this is my Controller:**

```
exports.getMembers = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user.role === "admin") {  
    try {
      const members = await User.find({ role: "member" });
      const products = await Product.find({ userId: { $in: members.map(m => m._id) } });

      res.render('admin/members', {
        path: '/admin/members',
        pageTitle: 'Members',
        members: members,
        Product: Product,
        products: products
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**And this is my View**

```
<ul class="orders">
   <% members.forEach(async member => { %>
     <li class="orders__item">
        <h1>Name: <%= member.name %></h1>
        <p>Email: <%= member.email %></p>
        <p>Joined: <%= member.joined.toLocaleString('es-ES', { hour12: false }) %></p>
        <hr style="height: 2px; background-color: white;" width="30%" align="left">        
        <h4>Products created by this user:</h4> 
        <div>
          <% let productsByMember = await Product.find({ userId: member._id }); %>
          <% productsByMember.forEach(item => { %>
                <p>Name: <%= item.title %></p>
                <p>Price: <%= item.price %></p>
          <% }); %>
         </div>   
       </li>
     <% }); %>                         
</ul>
```

There is no console.log errors or nothing that shows what it the problem, and still this is what I can see (not see) in the HTML page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mbDh.png)

I've check the DB (mongoDB) and it's all correct: i have the structure right, there is data were I am looking and if you console.log(itme.title or item.price) like this:

```
  <% productsByMember.forEach(item => { 
       console.log(item.title);
       console.log(item.price);
  %>
```

Works perfectly and I have output in the console.

**I want to print the information in the HTML page, thanks for your help :)**

Answer (score 0):

In controller iterate through members and add to each property of products array, so in the View you would need to present the data only

**Controller**

```
      const members = await User.find({ role: "member" });
      for (i=0; i<=members.length; i++) {
        members[i].products = await Product.find({ userId: members[i]._id });
      }
```

**View**

```
    <h4>Products created by this user:</h4> 
    <div>
      <% member.products.forEach(item => { %>
            <p>Name: <%= item.title %></p>
            <p>Price: <%= item.price %></p>
      <% }); %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, still doesn't work :(

Comment: i would add console.log after members[i].products =... to see what has been added

Comment: I've made one mistake in ...Product.find... line. Check it out now if it will fix something